# Rock Paper Scissors Compiler Error

Tags: java, object

I am trying to construct a rock paper scissors game that incorporates multiple classes together. I am struggling a lot with object oriented programming, and I cannot figure out how to correct my compiler error. Below is my code:

Main method:

```
 import java.util.*;

  public class RPSMain extends RPSPlayer{
   RPSPlayer player = new RPSPlayer();
   RPSGame gameObject = new RPSGame ();
   public  void main () 
   {


     Random generator = new Random ();
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print ("Number of Rounds: ");
     int rounds = sc.nextInt();


    //Call and process all of the methods found in RPSPlayer and RPSGame
    for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++){
   int playerThrow = player.makeThrow();
   int compThrow = gameObject.makeCompThrow();
   int winner = gameObject.announceWinner (compThrow, playerThrow );
   System.out.print (gameObject.bigWinner(winner, rounds));
}
    //Final Output
     System.out.print (gameObject.bigWinner(winner, rounds));
  }
//accessor to return round to RPSGame
   public  int getRound (int round){
     this.round = round;
     return round;
  }
}
```

Game method:

```
  import java.util.*;

 public class RPSGame extends RPSPlayer{
  RPSPlayer player = new RPSPlayer();
  RPSGame game = new RPSGame ();
  RPSMain mainRPS = new mainRPS();
   public void main (String args[]) {

     Random generator = new Random ();
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     int rounds = mainRPS.getRound(rounds);
   }
   //Random Throw Generator
   public  int makeCompThrow (){
     int Max = 3;
     int Min = 1;

     int compThrow =   Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));
     return compThrow;
  }

   //  Get the throw from the player in RPSPlayer
       public  int getPlayerThrow (){
     RPSPlayer player = new RPSPlayer();
     int getPThrow = player.makeThrow();
     return getPThrow;
  }

 //Does all of the calculatoins and ouputs who threw what.
   public  int announceWinner (int compThrow, int getPThrow) {
     int winner = 0;

     if (getPThrow == 1){
        System.out.println ("Player throws ROCK.");
     }
     else if (getPThrow == 2){
        System.out.println ("Player throws PAPER.");
     }
     else if (getPThrow == 3){
        System.out.println ("Player throws SCISSORS.");
     }


     if (compThrow == 1){
        System.out.println ("Computer throws ROCK.");
     }
     else if (compThrow == 2){
        System.out.println ("Computer throws PAPER.");
     }
     else if (compThrow == 3){
        System.out.println ("Computer throws SCISSORS.");
     }

     if (getPThrow == compThrow){
        winner = 3;
     }
     else if (getPThrow == 1 && compThrow == 3){
        winner = 1;
     }
     else if (getPThrow == 1 && compThrow == 2){
        winner = 2;
     }
     else if (getPThrow == 2 && compThrow == 1){
        winner = 1;
     }
     else if (getPThrow == 2 && compThrow == 3){
        winner = 2;
     }
     else if (getPThrow == 3 && compThrow == 1){
        winner = 2;
     }
     else if (getPThrow == 3 && compThrow == 2){
        winner = 1;
     }  

     return winner;
   }

//Final Output with imported values of 'rounds' and 'winner'
   public  int bigWinner (int winner, int rounds){
     int tie = 0;
     int playerWins = 0;
     int compWins = 0;

     if (winner == 1){
        playerWins = playerWins + 1;
     }

     else if (winner == 0){
        tie = tie + 1;
     }

     else if (winner == 3){
        compWins = compWins + 1;
     }
     System.out.println ("You win " +playerWins+ ". Computer wins " +(compWins)+ ".");
     if (playerWins > compWins){
        System.out.print ("You win!"); 
     }
     if (playerWins < compWins){
        System.out.print ("Computer wins!"); 
     }

     if (playerWins == compWins){
        System.out.print ("It's a tie!"); 
     }
     return tie;
  }


 }
```

Player method:

```
   import java.util.*;

  public class RPSPlayer {

  public  void main (String args[]) {
     Random generator = new Random ();
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  }
//This method gets the throw, and loops if throw is not within 1 and 3
  public  int makeThrow (){
     Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
     int playerThrow;
     do{
        System.out.print ("Enter your throw (1=Rock, 2=Paper, 3=Scissors)");
        playerThrow = sc.nextInt();
     } while (playerThrow > 3 && playerThrow < 1);
     return playerThrow;
  }

    //Accessor method
  public  int getThrow (int playerThrow){
    this.playerThrow = playerThrow;
     return playerThrow;
  }


 }
```

When I attempt to compile any of the classes, the error refers to code found in the RPSPlayer class:

```
cannot find symbol - variable playerThrow
```

As I said before, my knowledge of object-oriented program is very weak. I'm not really sure why I'm getting this error, as int playerThrow is defined right above it. I am also unsure if there are additional flaws or errors within my code. One thing I particularly struggle with is the concept of static vs. non-static code, and when to use which and what can be used within them.

Suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no instance variable named `playerThrow` in the `RPSPlayer` class. So, this line `this.playerThrow = playerThrow;` attempting to reference such a field is what's causing your error.

Comment: "int playerThrow is defined right above it. "  I think your error is a few lines below where you think it is. @Ryan has it right, but really, try with  a smaller example. RPSPlayer stands alone - compile that, and post the complete error.

Comment: I figured it had something to do with this line of code. However, when I remove it, another error surfaces: 

cannot find symbol - class mainRPS

However, RPSPlayer now compiles with error. But not RPSGame and RPSMain will not compile, and refer to where mainRPS is referenced in the RPSGame class.

Comment: Don't just remove it! If you need a instance variable for playerThrow, add one. And "another error" isn't very useful to the readers of this question.

Comment: `RPSMain mainRPS = new mainRPS();` should be `RPSMain mainRPS = new RPSMain();`, `public void main (String args[])` should be `public static void main (String args[])`, and all fields you refer to within that method should either be `static` or should be accessed by an instance to the class that defines them.Though from reading your code and looking at the names you've chosen to use, you have a lot more going on here than the simple error you created the question for. I might suggest some basic Java tutorials that will help you determine how you should structure your code.

Comment: Which class is your "main" class? (IE, the one used to invoke the program from the command line) The method signature for the main method is `public static void main(String[])`, which means it's a class-level method that exists without requiring an instance of the class to be created (you don't need to use `new` on the class to use it). In Java, non-static fields cannot be accessed from a static context. What this means is, you cannot access _instance_ level fields from a class level, without creating an _instance_ of the class first.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define the member variable, before you can assign a value to it. That's mandatory (obviously) for every class and every member variable.
Please add this to your class:

```
private int playerThrow;
```

Also, the function `getThrow` makes no sense. Getters return an already set value; setters are the one who actually give a value to your member variables. Do this instead:

```
public int getThrow()
{
    return playerThrow;
}

public void setThrow(int playerThrow)
{
    this.playerThrow = playerThrow;
}
```

Please note that `this.playerThrow` and `playerThrow` are not related in any way. `this.playerThrow` is a member variable of your class (defined as shown above) and `playerThrow` is a variable given as an argument to your method.

**EDIT:**

I'm addressing some more of your errors.

1. The problem you are referring to in your comment is because you are calling a constructor `mainRPS` while your class is called `RPSmain`. That's located here `RPSMain mainRPS = new mainRPS();` in the `RPSGame` class, in the start. Please fix this to `RPSMain mainRPS = new RPSMain();`.
2. Please define `private int round` in your RPSMain class. That's the same error as your first one addressed.
3. Also, define `int winner` outside the `for loop` because you're using it outside your loop, as well. When you define a value inside a loop, it will be local to that loop and will get destroyed when the program exits the loop.

Comment: Thank you the suggestion! That makes sense, not entirely sure what I was thinking when I added that without defining it. RPSPlayer now compiles fine, but please refer to my above comment, as that error is now surfacing instead.

Comment: I believe I have addressed all the errors of your code with my edit. I'll shape my answer a bit more to address the problems a bit more easily to understand.

Comment: First, thanks for all of these helps! I feel like such an idiot now that you've corrected all of my coding flaws. I implemented everything you mentioned, and changed my classes names to simply Player, Class, and Main. I figured the RPS was unnecessary. Anyway, I now have another compiled error within my Player class:

non-static method getRound(int) cannot be referenced from a static context

It is referring to this line of code:

int rounds = Main.getRound(rounds);

Comment: when you get the chance, would you mind seeing if you could give me a pointer on how to fix my current error?

Comment: This line of code is meant to call a static method. If you want to call a method which belongs to the "Main" class, you have to either define a "Main" (e.g. Main temp and then call temp.getRound(rounds);) or define getRound as static function.